# Get all rows with one of the top 2 values in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table with multiple entries and I have ordered it according to a sales criterion. So, if the entries are like:

```
Item  Sales
a     10
b     10
c     9
d     8
e     8
f     7
```

I want to extract the items with the highest and second highest number of sales. As such,
I would want to extract `a`, `b` and `c`.
Is there any function in PostgreSQL that can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include *all* rows with one of the top two sales values, you could use the [**`dense_rank()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) window function:

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT *
         ,dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY sales DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT item, sales
FROM   x
WHERE  rnk < 3;
```

You need PostgreSQL **8.4** or later for that.

---

For older versions, you could:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
JOIN   (
    SELECT sales
    FROM   tbl
    GROUP  BY 1
    ORDER  BY 1 DESC
    LIMIT  2
    ) t1 USING (sales)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ORDER BY and LIMIT:

```
  SELECT Item, Sales
    FROM mytable 
ORDER BY Sales DESC 
   LIMIT 2;
```

Results in:

```
item    sales
----    -----
a       10
b       9
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4966c/3)

Comment: Just curious... why (on earth) do you *right* align the first term(s) of each line?

Comment: But that does not take care of duplicates does it? For example if i have  
a  10
b  10
c   9
d   8

then you would want a,b and c but doesnt this only give you a and b?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Bohemian. I don't do that IRL. Seems easier to read, though, for the purposes of examples. Apparently not to everyone, though :D

Comment: @AnuragChaudhury: if there are duplicates you'll only get two rows with `LIMIT 2`:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3d58a/1

Comment: That's the point. I was wondering if there is any function which can be used to satisfy the condition and not just be limited to 2 tuples.

Comment: @AnuragChaudhury: I didn't get that at all from your question. You might consider updating the question to better make that point.